# How to automatically create large number of columns in Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I would like to start a new excel spreadsheet, create a column named Column1, and quickly fill in increments, (Column2, Column3 etc) up to Column500. Is there an easy way to do this?

Also is there an easy way to afterwards select all 500 columns and add 10 rows of data to all of them?

Comment: It is easy.................what values do you want in the columns ??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Simple integers from 1 to 10 would do. I know this isn't hard to do for one column, but I wouldn't be sure for 500 columns simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you need to change reference style: go to file - options - formulas and check "R1C1 reference style"

### Creating headers:

- Go to the small box in the left of formula bar and type `R1C1:R1C500` then press Enter, this select the desired range
  [image]
- type the formula `="column" & COLUMN()` then press CTRL+Enter
- press CTRL+C then go to home - paste and select "values"

### Filling random data:

- go to address bar and type `R2C1:R101C500`
- Enter formula `=RANDBETWEEN(0,10)` and press CTRL+Enter
- press CTRL+C then go to home - paste and select "values"

Finally you may want to change back reference style from R1C1.